# ComboBox not populating correctly

Tags: c#, .net

I use following code to populate a Combo Box. It displays: System.Data.DataRowView instead of the actual column values in it. What I am missing?

```
        string Query = "SELECT institutename FROM institutemaster";
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(Query, ConnectionClass.CN);
        da.Fill(ds, "Institutes");
        cmbInstitutes.DataSource = ds.Tables["Institutes"];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to set [DisplayMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember.aspx) and [ValueMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.valuemember.aspx) properties:

```
cmbInstitutes.DisplayMember = "NameOfTheColumnForText";
cmbInstitutes.ValueMember = "NameOfTheColumnForValues";
```

or [DataValueField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datavaluefield.aspx) and [DataTextField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datatextfield.aspx) if it is an ASP.NET application.

Comment: Ok, and if I want to populate two columns in the same ComboBox, then how to do?

Comment: You add a calculated column: http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2003/05/26/datacolumn_expressions.html

Answer (score 1):

you can populate two columns  in same combobox using following code.

```
string Query = "SELECT (institutename +', '+city) as Institute  FROM institutemaster";
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();   
 MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(Query, ConnectionClass.CN);        
da.Fill(ds, "Institutes");    
cmbInstitutes.DataSource = ds.Tables["Institutes"];
cmbInstitutes.DisplayMember = "Institute";
cmbInstitutes.ValueMember = "Institute";
```